# Making a Ctrl-F Feature for wx.TextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, find, wxtextctrl

I'm attempting to make a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Find) feature for a `wx.TextCtrl` widget. However I'm unsure of how to highlight certain indexes/phrases. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`wx.TextCtrl.SetSelection(from, to)`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxtextctrl.html#wxtextctrlsetselection)